How to make this draggable view that acts like bottomsheet, but its not bottomsheet
I am trying to do that scrollable/draggable view like in google maps (Latest in the area). This is not bottom sheet, I am trying to find a way to do it but i cannot find a proper way. i think maybe its done with animations.

I can use these:
view.animate().translationY(distance)

view.animate().translationY(0)


but how to do in not on clicking but by dragging them, if i drag it up it should slide up, if i drag it down it should slide down
